# Generating four numbers (N +- i +- j)

Tags: loops, numbers

I have four numbers that I am trying to generate without hardcoding.

I want to take a number N +- 18 +- 2. So I want N + 16, N + 20, N - 16, N - 20.

Is there any good way with a loop to generate these numbers using only the numbers 18 and 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, because you want the all the combinations of + and - to a pair of constant i,j, iterate over +-1 for each one, one loop inside the other and in the most inner loop build the desire result. In pseudo-code it would be something like this:

```
function(N,i,j):
    for x in [1,-1]:
        for y in [1,-1]:
            print N + x*i + y*j
```